How to tell action Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@1 to use dev environment file within react app
I'm new to github actions and I'm trying to deploy a newly created vite + react.js application to our development azure static web app. I have environment files for .env.development and .env.production. In the case below when it builds I want it to use the .env.development file.
It is defaulting to npm run build and using the production file.
env:
  APP_LOCATION: "/" # location of your client code
  OUTPUT_LOCATION: "dist" # location of client code build output

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - develop

permissions:
  issues: write
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: ${{ env.APP_LOCATION }}
          output_location: ${{ env.OUTPUT_LOCATION }}

  close_pull_request:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          action: "close"


I'm not familiar with this action, but I assume the AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN secret is different for each environment, right? In that case, you could save those tokens for each environment as secret, and inform the environment where your deployment is occurring in the job configuration calling the action.
